# Как запустить accordion дважды

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Необходимо запустить accordion на одной странице дважды.

Пример аккордеона:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если просто разместить вызов аккордеона на странице дважды, то первый будет нормально работать, а второй нет. Подскажите, как два одинаковых аккордеона запустить на одной странице?

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <h2>Accordion 1 </h2>
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="row">
     <h2>Accordion 2 </h2>
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#collapse1-2">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#collapse2-2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#collapse3-2">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание на:

- `id` второго аккордеона - `id="accordion-2"`
- `data` атрибуты ссылок - `data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#collapse1-2"`
- `panel-collapse` - `id="collapse1-2"`

P.S: `id` на странице может быть в единственном экземпляре, повторного использования одного и того же `id` не должно быть!